# View the display out signal on main monitor?

Tags: video, display, macbook-pro, projector

I am running an event for my community soon an I need software where I can see the contants of the two projects when they are in "No Show" mode. Is it possible to see what is being displayed through the two displays (being powered by two Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapters on my rMBP) without having the projectors on?

Comment: I've spent some time searching, but I haven't found anything useful. It shouldn't be hard to make though, so if any OS X developers come across this, feel free to make it yourselves! :)

Comment: Just mirroring it might work. I know that with my Thunderbolt-to-DVI-connected display, my Mac can't tell whether the display is on or not.